# How to allow sites to save and read cookie data in Xamarin.Forms WebView?

Tags: xamarin, cookies, webview, xamarin.forms

Is there an option in the `WebView` to allow sites to save and read cookie data.
I looked at some tutorials, all describe how to set cookies, but I need to allow them?

For example there's this option in Google Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an option in the WebView to allow sites to save and read cookie data?

In fact, you don't have to do it. If you just want to read and save the cookie,you can use [CookieManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) in Android and [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nshttpcookiestorage?language=occ)  in iOS .